# What is the use case of nextFocusDown, nextFocusForward and others ? Is it for android mobile or TV?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to know the use case of following properties of view and is it for android mobile or TV?

- nextFocusDown
- nextFocusForward
- nextFocusLeft
- nextFocusRight
- nextFocusUp

React native [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#nextfocusdown-android) is not enough to understand and I am not a native app developer. Examples would be more appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Those properties refer to the basic Android API, both mobile and TV. They define the next view to give focus to when the next focus direction matches.
F.e. `nextFocusDown` connected to `View.FOCUS_DOWN` direction and etc.

You can find full Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:nextFocusDown)

The popular usage example is a screen with a lot of input fields where those properties simplify navigation between fields and speed up typing.

For the practical usage [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75339677/6072908) may help